# Android Finish activity with videoview very slow

Tags: android, performance, android-videoview

I have a button to stop my videoview and close current activity and show previous activity. But the process is very slow (about 8 seconds)

Here my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == ivSkip.getId()) {
        ivSkip.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_skip_selected);
        videoView.stopPlayback();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Videoview is stopping quickly but the current activity close is very slow.
What is the problem? Can somebody help me?

Regards

Comment: You are probably doing something heavy in one of the activity's lifecycle methods which are called when an activity is about to be destroyed. I mean `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy`.